# RSQLite number of characters in a sql command

Tags: sql, r, database, rsqlite

I try to cerate a complex SQL command in R with RSQLite. I recive the error only up to 1000 characters are allowed in an SQL command. I read that SQLite can handel up to 1 million characters. How I can grow up the limitation in R code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510707/is-there-any-limit-on-sqlite-query-size ? it will also help to see the error message and to know where you see it

Comment: Try updating your RSQLite to the latest and see if it makes any difference.  This works for me and has over 10,000 characters.   `s <- paste("select", toString(1:2000)); library(sqldf); out <- sqldf(s)`   Also are you sure it complained about characters and not number of columns?